# Simplifying $ \left(\frac{mn}{l}\times\frac{m-l}{n^2}\right) ÷ \left(\frac{m}{l+m}÷\frac{l}{n}\right) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I simplify this:

$$
\left(\frac{mn}{l}\times\frac{m-l}{n^2}\right) ÷ \left(\frac{m}{l+m}÷\frac{l}{n}\right)
$$

The answer is the following, but I am unable to produce the answer myself:

$$
\frac{m^2-l^2}{n^2}
$$

Comment: Hello, use the fact that to divide by a fraction, you multiply by its inverse.

Comment: To further clarify @Mateo_13's suggestion,
$$a\div b=a\times\frac{1}{b}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\left(\frac{mn}{l}\times\frac{m-l}{n^2}\right)\div\left(\frac{m}{l+m}\div\frac{l}{n}\right)$

$=\left(\frac{m}{l}\times\frac{m-l}{n}\right)\div\left(\frac{m}{l+m}\times\frac{n}{l}\right)$

$=\frac{m\left(m-l\right)}{ln}\div\frac{mn}{l\left(l+m\right)}$

$=\frac{m\left(m-l\right)}{ln}\times\frac{l\left(l+m\right)}{mn}$

$=\frac{m-l}{n}\times\frac{l+m}{n}$

$=\frac{m-l}{n}\times\frac{m+l}{n}$

$=\frac{m^2-l^2}{n^2}$

Answer (score 0):

This is to expand on Mateo_13's comment.

You want to solve $$
\left(\frac{mn}{l}\times\frac{m-l}{n^2}\right) ÷ \left(\frac{m}{l+m}÷\frac{l}{n}\right)
$$

Lets focus on
$\left(\frac{mn}{l}\times\frac{m-l}{n^2}\right)$ first. When multiplying fractions we multiply the numerator and denominator together. Hence we obtain
$$\left( \frac{mn(m-l)}{ln^2} \right) ÷ \left(\frac{m}{l+m}÷\frac{l}{n}\right)$$ To divide fractions we reciprocate the xpression to the right of the symbol. For example, $$\frac{1}{2} \div \frac{3}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$$ Applying this to your example we have
$$\left( \frac{mn(m-l)}{ln^2} \right) ÷ \left(\frac{m}{l+m} \times \frac{n}{l}\right)$$ Multiplying the fractions together we obtain $$\left( \frac{mn(m-l)}{ln^2} \right) ÷ \left(\frac{mn}{l(l+m)}\right)$$ Reciprocating we have $$\left( \frac{mn(m-l)}{ln^2} \right) \times \left(\frac{l(l+m)}{mn}\right)$$ Combining these expressions we have $$\left( \frac{mnl(m-l)(m+l)}{ln^2mn} \right)$$ Notice how we have $mnl$ on both the numerator and denominator, we can cancel them. Also notice that $(m+l)(m-l)$ represents a difference of two squares. So,

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\left( \frac{mnl(m-l)(m+l)}{ln^2mn} \right) & = \left( \frac{mnl \left[ (m-l)(m+l) \right]}{mnl \left( n^2 \right)} \right) \\&= \left( \frac{\cancel{mnl} \left[ (m-l)(m+l) \right]}{\cancel{mnl} \left( n^2 \right)} \right)  \\ &= \left( \frac{\left[ (m-l)(m+l) \right]}{ \left( n^2 \right)} \right) \\&= \frac{m^2 - l^2}{n^2}
\end{align} As required.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the variable $e$ instead of the variable $l$ in your original question because $l$ is easily confused with the number $1$ (at least for me).

I will assume that all the denominators are not equal to zero in the entire post.

Simplify:

$$
K=\left(\frac{mn}{e}\times\frac{m-e}{n^2}\right) ÷ \left(\frac{m}{e+m}÷\frac{e}{n}\right)
$$

Please note the following rules:

$$\frac{A}{\left(\frac{B}{C}\right)}\:=\frac{AC}{B}$$

and

$$\frac{\left(\frac{A}{X}\right)}{\left(\frac{B}{C}\right)}\:=\left(\frac{A}{X}\right)\left(\frac{C}{B}\right)$$

Back to your problem, using the first rule above:

$$K\:=\:\frac{m\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)\:\:\:\cdot \frac{m\:-e}{n^2}}{\frac{m}{e+m}\:\cdot \left(\frac{n}{e}\:\right)}\:\:$$

$Cancel\:\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)\:\:to\:get:$
$$\frac{\:m\:\left(\frac{m\:-e}{n^2}\right)}{\left(\frac{m}{e+m}\right)}$$

$Cancel\:m\:to\:get:\:$

$$\frac{\:\:\left(\frac{m\:-e}{n^2}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{e+m}\right)}$$

Apply first rule above to get:
$$\left(\frac{m\:-e}{n^2}\right)\:\left(e+m\right)$$

$$K=\frac{m^2-e^2}{n^2}$$